# Why was this question considered primarily opinion based?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-close, close-reasons, closed-questions

The question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660999/enum-nested-in-class-vs-interface

The reason:

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely **based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise**.

OP asked about the differences between the strategies. He never asked about which one was better or worse, so no opinions would be involved. I was actually writing an answer to it based on the compiled Java bytecode (i.e. basing my answer on a fact) when the question was closed.

OP's original final question was:

> Is there any reason to choose one case over the other, and at what level do these two implementations differ?

After the question was closed, he edited it to:

> At what level do these two implementations differ?

I believe the question was valid for both cases, though. It's a valid question about the difference of a detail most of us would find not very important. But regardless, it's definitely a non-opinion-based question.

Comment: Really this should be "Too Broad" as it's asking for an unbounded list of *any* possible difference.  The question should be narrowed by asking about a specific difference, or differences relevant to a particular context/situation.  "What's the difference" questions are very rarely well suited to SO.

Comment: @Servy Any possible difference between two very specific situations. I don't see it as too broad or leading to an unbounded list of differences.

Comment: It's essentially asking for all of the differences between an interface and a class, because all of them would be differences between an enum in an interface and an enum in a class.

Comment: @Servy No, it's not. Using a nested enum from an interface or class has, at first, no difference whatsoever, even though classes and interfaces are definitely very different. And I believe that's exactly OP's motivation for the question: "*if classes and interfaces have all those differences, do nested enums within them also have any differences?*". It was, at least, how I got interested in the question.

Comment: That doesn't mean that there aren't differences, it means that those differences may not be relevant to him (however its quite possible that some of them *would* be relevant).  But without the question specifically describing the situation, you can't actually exclude anything for that reason.  If the question describes the situation that the enums are used in, and what the code needs to do, one could succinctly show which (if any) of the two snippets successfully accomplish it.  That would be one way of narrowing the question down.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913098/what-is-the-difference-between-an-interface-and-abstract-class Is this question narrow enough, to you? Because following your line it is not, even though it's a protected question with hundreds of upvotes. You say "*'What's the difference' questions are very rarely well suited to SO.*", but I can think of so many great questions like that out there.

Comment: Here are two of them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java

Comment: But hey, it's a 100k against a 1k. That's probably why the question is already gone.

Comment: It has never been that clear to me why Bohemian wants to be a moderator.  Sometimes life can be a lot easier if your vote just counts as one-of-five.

Comment: Of your examples, the second (string vs String) isn't too broad in that the answer is, "there is no difference", and there is very little explanation that need happen.  For the other two, they're unquestionably too broad in my mind.  The answer to neither question are actually providing a complete answer, they're merely posting one or two (of *many*) differences.  Both are ignoring many (often relevant and important) differences, and including all of them would be *well* beyond the scope appropriate for an SO question.  One will often devote chapters of intro programming books to the former.

Comment: @HansPassant 100% agree with the first sentence.  Not even sure if the second is true.  It tends to create more drama.

Comment: Why are there vote limits (rhetorical)? I keep trying to upvote the comments here and getting the error that I've used my vote allowance for the day. It's like the dev's think I should go outside at some point or some such nonsense.

Comment: @Servy OP's question actuall fall in the same category of the *string vs String* question. There is no difference and all I was gonna do was prove that by comparing the bytecode generated. Since both enums are `static`, none of the differences between classes and interfaces would actually interfere with the enum usage.

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula "But hey, it's a 100k against a 1k. That's probably why the question is already gone." For the record, it was deleted by the author.

Comment: I know. He's not aware of this topic.

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula That's not true.  There would be differences; lots of them, it's just plausible (but not a certainty) that the author wouldn't care about them.  For the `string` vs `String` question *it actually generates identical code*.  It's impossible to observe the difference in the program in any way, because they're literally indistinguishable.  Not true in this case here.

Comment: No, that's the thing: **for the enum**, the code generated is exactly the same, regardless if the enum is nested within a class or an interface. You're basing your opinion on what you believe is the answer of the question. Try looking at the question for itself.

Comment: I give up, though. And sorry about that comment, I was a little frustrated.

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula I closed it as "opinion based" because there's no difference from a code perspective - it comes down to a matter of *style*, and the difference (if any) is subjective.

Comment: @Bohemian So you closed because you knew the answer?

Comment: I deleted the question because I figured it was dead in the water. Didn't realize it was being discussed here. It's back up now.